# Applying discrete Wigner-Ville distribution to Lena picture?

Tags: image-processing

It seems that 2D Wigner-Ville has been used to test the compression of data.
The interference is however a problem.

**Can someone send me a link to a code where this has been done?**
I want to study the code and change it little study the compression and Wigner distribution.

---

[Here](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/), seems to be basic steps to make 512x512 matrix out of the picture.

1. So it is now only the application of the distribution to the image.
2. Then, JPEG2000 compression of the resulted image to test.
3. And make a plot PSNR(dB) as a function of Coding Rate (bits per pixel).

**Where and how can you apply Wigner-Ville to the image?**

I need to apply the function and Fourier transformation to every single pixel of the picture, [here](http://optica.csic.es/papers/ipwig.rev.pdf).

I have the Lena picture in 512x512 in Matlab, done by

```
lena512 = imread('lena512.bmp');
lena512 = double(lena512);
```

---

I am reading the [package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35092-wavelet-scale-spectra/content/Wavelets/Wavelab850/Datasets/lenna.txt) here and thinking where Wigner has been possibly been applied.
Not sure if used at all.
However, it speaks there something about autocorrelation so it can be possibly applied in code:

> The long-range correlations in the original series are eliminated by
>   the wavelet transform, and that the wavelet coefficients form series
>   with virtually no autocorrelation or cross-correlation.

**Where Wigner Distribution has been applied to the Lena picture?**

Comment: Can you provide references to where it has been used? I don't see it in in the provided package.

Comment: [Complete aside: I used to refer to the WVD of 1D signals as $W_a(n,k)$.](http://espace.library.uq.edu.au/eserv/UQ:11271/n00149998.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The developers of [Lucid](http://qualvisual.net/Lucid.php), which is based on time-frequency analysis, report interesting results. Technical details are provided in this [PowerPoint file](https://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.qualvisual.net/DownLoadTime.php&ei=mOhkUtCtEfD50gXlwIHQAQ&usg=AFQjCNGgxTqkZ9ktiSwKkq_-vHY6RKUlYg&sig2=FophIyrnzUGE5yWidn96AQ&bvm=bv.54934254,d.d2k).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the paper :
[A. Beghdadi, R. Iordache, “Image quality Assessment using the Joint Space/ Spatial-Frequency Representation”, EURASIP Journal on Applied Signal Processing, Volume 2006, Article ID 80537, 2006, Pages 1–8.(PDF)](http://www-l2ti.univ-paris13.fr/~beghdadi/jasp2006_SNR_W.pdf)

A. Beghdadi

Comment: Do you which code they are using? Is that publicly available for review?